# I am trying to write a trigger to search that column for duplicates before inserting a value so that i can not have the same value in the column

Tags: sql

I am am new to SQL 2008 R2, I am trying to write a trigger to search in a column called AlphanumericCol for duplicates before inserting a value so that I can not have the same value in the column

What I have so far:

```
ALTER TRIGGER DUPLICATES
ON  AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl

AFTER INSERT,
  UPDATE
AS

Declare @Counter integer
Declare @Value integer

set @Counter = (Select top 1 AlphanumericCol from AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl order by AlphanumericCol  desc); -- this will bring back the last record
set @Value = @Counter + 1;



IF EXISTS(select top 1 * from AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl order by AlphanumericCol desc)
 BEGIN
  RAISERROR('This row already exists in the table', 16, 1)
  ROLLBACK TRAN
 END;
```

But does not seem to work

Thanks in advance

Comment: why unique constraint is not an option?

Comment: You need some sort of comparison in the `exists` clause to `@Value`.  But a `unique` constraint/index is really the way to go.

Comment: i have tried a unique constraint.. but i need to use a trigger... i have no idea how to do the comparison on the @value? like this: select @Value from AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl order by AlphanumericCol desc?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is probably:

```
alter table AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl add constraint ... unique ( AlphanumericCol );
```

If that won't work for some reason you must look in the table for a specific value before raising an error (you will get an error if there exists an row regardless of value for AlphanumericCol). I don't know sql-server so this might contain errors but something like:

```
ALTER TRIGGER DUPLICATES
    ON  AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
    IF EXISTS(select 1 
              from AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl as x
              join inserted AS y 
                  ON x.AlphanumericCol = y.AlphanumericCol)    
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('This row already exists in the table', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRAN
    END;
```

Comment: You insert into the table, the trigger raises an error in case of duplicates, otherwise does nothing. The trigger does not "replace" your insert, it does something in addition to your insert. There are other types of triggers that does an additional insert (logging, auditing), but I dont think that is the case here. Did that clarify the purpose of the trigger?

Comment: BTW, what is the problem with a unique constraint, it sounds as if it would fit like a glove for your scenario?